# angular ag-grid how to style the header

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid in my angular application and trying to export to excel. I want to style the header row in the excel. Can anyone help me how to achieve this? I tried the below but doesnt seems to be working.

```
   this.excelStyles = [
      {
        id: 'smallFont',
        font: {
          fontName:'Calibri',
          size: 9
        }
      },
      {
        id:'blueBackground',
        interior: {
          color: 'blue',
          pattern: 'solid'
        }
      }
    ]

defaultColDef: {
  cellClassRules: {
    smallFont: (params) => true,
    blueBackground: (params) => params.rowIndex == 0
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seting the excelstyle with id 'header' as shown below will set style for the excel headers.

```
{
  id:'header',
  interior: {
    color: '#002776',
    pattern: 'solid'
  },
  font: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontName: 'Calibri',
    size: 9,
    bold: true
  }
}
```